# How to keep docker container running via python docker SDK?

Tags: python, docker, flask

I have an iamge which is a flask app.

I am trying to run it, like so:

```
import docker
import requests


client = docker.from_env()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    client.containers.run(IMAGE_NAME, detach=True, ports={"1000/tcp": "1000"})
    res = requests.get("http://localhost:1000/health")
    print(res.status_code)
```

The flask app:

```
@app.route("/health")
def health_check():
    return "healthy"



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True, port=int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000)))
```

However I get an error:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
```

Presumably the connection dies out after `run` ends?

How do I make it so that the app keeps running in the background?

My dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3

# set a directory for the app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# copy all the files to the container
COPY . .

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# tell the port number the container should expose
EXPOSE 5000

# run the command
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

Comment: Could you add the Dockerfile for the Image? The python code seems to be fine. I think the Image lifecycle is completed as soon as it boot's up. Could you check whether the image is actually running using `docker ps`?

Comment: @SaiprasadBalasubramanian yes, docker ps does indeed show a row for the image

Comment: The flask application inside the container is running on port 5000 and your script is checking for the health check endpoint on 1000, is that right?

Comment: @SaiprasadBalasubramanian actually I was under the impression that  1000 in the program would override the `EXPOSE` param in the dockerfile.

Comment: No, you'll need to link port 5000 of the container to port 5000 of the host machine. EXPOSE just exposes it but doesn't bind it with the host machine

Comment: @SaiprasadBalasubramanian right okay. So yes, I want to map 5000 of the container to 1000 of the host machine. That's what I've tried in the code

Answer (score 1):

Running the container using the following should solve the issue
`client.containers.run(IMAGE_NAME, detach=True, ports={"5000/tcp": "5000"})` which binds port 5000 of the container to port 5000 of the host machine.

Ports 0 to 1024 are strictly reserved for OS applications, it's always adviced to use ports greater than 1024 for the host machine. However, to use ports less than 1024 you'll need to have sudo access which is not advisable.

Comment: So this kinda works. When I ran the code above, I got the same exception as above. But then I ran the script again, this time uncommented `client.containers.run(...)` -- and I got back the response I wanted

Comment: The error I got the first time was: `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
`

Comment: I tested out the code. The issue is that your `requests` code is pinging the port before the application has started inside the container. Try adding a small sleep between running the container and pinging the port. 5 seconds worked perfectly for me

Comment: is there a better way to do this? I would ideally like some form of `await`

Comment: You could use requests to have a timeout while checking to see the server status. You could pass timeout in the following way: `res = requests.get("http://localhost:5000/health", timeout=10)` where 10 is the second's requests would wait for **any** response data initiated by the server. Check out https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#timeouts

Answer (score 0):

Add a few sleeps in conjunction with @Saiprasad's answer solved this issue:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    container = client.containers.run(IMAGE_NAME, detach=True, ports={"5000/tcp": "5000"})
    import time
    time.sleep(1)
    res = requests.get("http://localhost:5000/health")

    print(res.status_code)
    print(res.text)
    container.kill()
    time.sleep(1)
```